# pandas read_excel only loads 5 rows

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am working on to read securities list information using pandas, however, it is found that I can only load 5 rows into my environment, the same code works fine at colab platform.

Here is my code snippet

```
url = r'https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/services/trading/securities/securitieslists/ListOfSecurities.xlsx'
df_list = pd.read_excel(url,skiprows=2,engine="openpyxl")
```

my environment version information
python 3.9.1 (64 bit)
pandas 1.2.1
openpyxl 3.0.6

Anything wrong here? Please help advice. thanks!

Comment: I had to download the `xlsx` file and save it to a `csv` to get it to work. Otherwise it also only loaded 5 rows. I don't know why. Also, if I saved it to a new `xlsx` file, all the rows were loaded with `.read_excel`.

Comment: Got the same result as @TrentonMcKinney

Comment: I should note, I'm also using `openpyxl 3.0.6` and `pandas 1.2.1`, but `python 3.8.5` 64 bit. Seems like this is an issue with the file, since it works with a new xlsx file from save as.

Comment: The problem is that worksheet is declared to be small: `<x:dimension ref="A1:U8" />`. Pandas is probably using openpyxl in read-only mode for speed and uses this information if it's available. In openpyxl directly you can workaround this.

Answer (score 0):

This is very weird as for me too it wasn't working. But I come up with using following which actually uses openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import urllib
from io import BytesIO

url = r'https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/services/trading/securities/securitieslists/ListOfSecurities.xlsx'
wb = load_workbook(filename = BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()))
ws = wb.active
data = list(ws.values)
df_list = pd.DataFrame(data[2:], columns=data[3])
```

Comment: It looks like a bug of openpyxl, I change the engine to use xlrd 1.1.0 and the program works fine now